# Automatically creating an array out of a certain type of objects Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have 2 classes, Species and CircleofLife

in CircleofLife, I have created several new Species objects like so

```
Species cat = new Species("Felid", 20, 1.84);
Species human = new Species("Homo Sapiens", 1500, 1.1);
Species amoeba = new Species("Amoeba", 2000000000, 20);
Species bacteria = new Species("bacteria", 20000000,20);
```

Now, I have a method in Species called kill which sets the population and growth rate values to 0. I am looking for a way to dynamically create an array that I can iterate over using code like this:

```
for(Species species : circleOfDeath)
{
    species.kill;
}
```

this is approximately what I would like to have happen.

```
get all objects of type Species.
create an array of type Species[]
add all objects of type Species to the array.
```

I could just manually create the array, but then I have more work if I want to add more species, and especially if I were to use a for loop to import data and create species off of that data.

Comment: Java does not have a way to get all objects of a particular type. While you *can* make one yourself, *it will cause you a lot more headaches than it will solve in the long run*.

Comment: can you be more elaborate. I am certainly not understanding what you mean by the first killing and then repopulating things.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate with some pseudocode prefably?

Comment: what is circleOfDeath?

Comment: Immibis is there not a way to use type reflection

Answer (score -1):

instead of using an array, which is lot of work to use it dynamically, try

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

There are other Lists as well (sortable etc.)